# Dell Inspiron 5110 proper drivers for Linux Mint 'Qiana' 32bit/64bit

Tags: linux-mint, drivers

I decided to move on Linux and choose the Mint 'Qiana' distribution.No Windows no more! But It's a little more tricky with Linux. I need a little guidance here, I cannot find all the drivers for Dell Inspiron N5110 with params.:

- Intel core I5 - 2.50Ghz, 64bit;
- Video nVidia 525M and build-in Intel Graphics.
- 6GB ram

Comment: +1 for NWNM. Have you already tried to install and doesn't the system allow you to select any drivers (Menu -> Administration -> Driver Manager?

Comment: What drivers are missing? Please [edit] and tell us exactly what hardware you need the driver for. Also, add the model of your graphics card, what you've given us is just a description (open a terminal and run `lspci -k | grep VGA`, that should give more details). Also, try running "Driver Manager" from the menu. That will help install missing drivers.

Comment: This is my list with drivers for my computer to function properly. - http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/servicetag/5N8VKR1/drivers< br/>